# Washing road bike with iron-rich water

Tags: road-bike, cleaning

I was searching for information concerning washing the bike with iron-rich water, but haven't found anything so far. The water coming out of my garden hose is naturally rich in iron. I have cleaned couple of times both mine and my girlfriend's road bikes, but I noticed no problem. I was wondering if continuing doing so might have bad effects in the short and long periods. Is there anybody of you having experience with it?

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: I do not think it could cause anything apart from some staining.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the iron-rich water will cause problems unless you put the bike away wet.

So, wash and then let it dry in the sunlight for a while, then turn the bike around and let it dry on the other side.   Or you could use an automotive chamois or a powered air blaster to help dry the bike off.